# Can you apply continuous mapping theorem for sequence of random variables that diverges to infinity?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, convergence

Let there be a sequence of real-valued random variables, $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and suppose that either $X_n \overset{p}{\to} c < \infty$ or $X_n \overset{\textrm{a.s.}}{\to} c < \infty$. Also let $\phi(\cdot)$ be the standard Normal density function, which is a continuous function. The continuous mapping theorem would imply that $\phi(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} \phi(c)$ or $\phi(X_n) \overset{\textrm{a.s.}}{\to} \phi(c)$.

However, what if either $X_n \overset{p}{\to} \infty$ or $X_n \overset{\textrm{a.s.}}{\to} \infty$. Can we apply the continuous mapping theorem to claim that $\phi(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} 0$ or $\phi(X_n) \overset{\textrm{a.s.}}{\to} 0$ since the continuous, standard Normal density function tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$?

If we cannot apply the continuous mapping theorem in general under weak or strong divergence of $X_n$ to $\infty$, is it sufficient to simply reason that the standard Normal density is monotonically decreasing toward $0$ as $x$ increases from 0 toward $\infty$? Therefore, $\phi(X_n)$ will converge (either weakly or strongly) to $0$ as $X_n$ diverges (either weakly or strongly) to $\infty$ ...

Thanks to all for any insights.

Comment: It seems to me that when you define $Y_n=1/X_n$ your question reduces to the case $c=0$ and is answered by noticing that the function $y \to \phi(1/y)$ is continuous (in fact, infinitely differentiable) everywhere.